# Price change depends on visitors IP address Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price

**Magento 1.9**

I need to build a new functionality for price change depends on visitors IP address.

Price will be changed depends on visitors country.

There is any free extension for this functionality or any guidance to build this functionality manually.

Please suggest some idea build this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As standard, price can be set on a per website basis. In `System > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope > Website`

So, if you then set up a **new website** within your Magento **for each country** you will be able to use the configuration scope to select and set the price for each countries website.

**Redirect customer to store view by GeoIP auto switch store view extension:** [GeoIP Currency/Store Switcher - Free](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/geoip-currency-store-switcher-free.html)

**Source** : Quora and Google